# How do I get a nested anonymous function to open links in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

How do I make this Javascript to open on a new page when
I've created an allSelect variable referencing all select elements nested within the govLinks form (it works but opens on the same window).

Within the nested anonymous function, I need to retrieve tge value of the property of evt.target and store it in the linkURL variable

Within the nested anonymous function I also need to use the window.open() method to open a new browser or any window options. Store the window under the newWin variable.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my current Javascript code.

```
// Function invoked when window is loaded, and it is an anonymous function

window.onload = function () {
    // Get all select elements in 'govlinks'
    var allSelect = document.getElementById("govLinks").querySelectorAll("select");

    // Loop on all the select elements and attach an event to them
    for (var i = 0; i < allSelect.length; i++) {
        allSelect[i].onchange = function (evt) {
            console.log(evt.target.value);
            location.href = evt.target.value; // Update location href
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<article>
    <form id="govLinks" name="govLinks">
        <h1>Government Sites on the Web</h1>
        <p>Select a site from one of the drop-down lists below.</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Executive Branch</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="executive" id="executive" class="optionLinks">
                        <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
                        <option value="http://www.whitehouse.gov">The White House</option>
                        <option value="http://www.usda.gov">Department of Agriculture</option>
                        <option value="http://www.doc.gov">Department of Commerce</option>
                        <option value="http://www.defenselink.mil">Department of Defense</option>
                        <option value="http://www.ed.gov">Department of Education</option>
                        <option value="http://www.energy.gov">Department of Energy</option>
                        <option value="http://www.hhs.gov">Department of Health and Human 
           Services</option>
                        <option value="http://www.whitehouse.gov/homeland">Department of Homeland 
          Security</option>
                        <option value="http://www.hud.gov">Department of Housing and Urban 
           Development</option>
                        <option value="http://www.doi.gov">Department of the Interior</option>
                        <option value="http://www.usdoj.gov">Department of Justice</option>
                        <option value="http://www.dol.gov">Department of Labor</option>
                        <option value="http://www.state.gov">Department of State</option>
                        <option value="http://www.ustreas.gov">Department of the Treasury</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Legislative Branch</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="legislative" id="legislative" class="optionLinks">
                        <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
                        <option value="http://www.house.gov">House Web Site</option>
                        <option value="http://clerk.house.gov/">Clerk of the House</option>
                        <option value="http://www.senate.gov">Senate Web Site</option>
                        <option value="http://www.senate.gov/general/contact_information/senators_cfm.cfm">Senators' 
          Web Sites</option>
                        <option value="http://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/common/generic/Senate_Historical_Office.htm">Senate Historic Office</option>
                        <option value="http://www.cq.com">Congressional Quarterly</option>
                        <option value="http://www.loc.gov/">Library of Congress</option>
                        <option value="http://www.gao.gov/">Government Accountability Office</option>
                        <option value="http://www.cbo.gov/">Congressional Budget Office</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Judicial Branch</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="judicial" id="judicial" class="optionLinks">
                        <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
                        <option value="http://www.uscourts.gov">U.S. Courts</option>
                        <option value="https://www.supremecourt.gov/">U.S. Supreme Court</option>
                        <option value="http://www.uscourts.gov/courtsofappeals.html">U.S. Courts of Appeals</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State Governments</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="state" id="state" class="optionLinks">
                        <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/index.cfm">State and Local Government on the Net</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-al.cfm">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ak.cfm">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-az.cfm">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ar.cfm">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ca.cfm">California</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-co.cfm">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ct.cfm">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-de.cfm">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-dc.cfm">District of Columbia</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-fl.cfm">Florida</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ga.cfm">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-hi.cfm">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-id.cfm">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-il.cfm">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-in.cfm">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ia.cfm">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ks.cfm">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ky.cfm">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-la.cfm">Louisana</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-me.cfm">Maine</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-md.cfm">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ma.cfm">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-mi.cfm">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-mn.cfm">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ms.cfm">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-mo.cfm">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-mn.cfm">Montana</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ne.cfm">Nebraska</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-nv.cfm">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-nh.cfm">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-nj.cfm">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-nm.cfm">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ny.cfm">New York</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-nc.cfm">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-nd.cfm">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-oh.cfm">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ok.cfm">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-or.cfm">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-pa.cfm">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ri.cfm">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-sc.cfm">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-sd.cfm">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-tn.cfm">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-tx.cfm">Texas</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-ut.cfm">Utah</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-vt.cfm">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-va.cfm">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-wa.cfm">Washington</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-wv.cfm">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-wi.cfm">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="http://www.statelocalgov.net/state-wy.cfm">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</article>
```

javascript
html
for-loop

Comment: I fixed the layout of your code and HTML - please try to post code that is readable

Comment: *Within the nested anonymous function I also need to use the window.open() method to open a new browser or any window options. Store the window under the newWin variable.* - then do that, what happens when you actually try?

Comment: by the way `var allSelect = document.getElementById("govLinks").querySelectorAll("select");` can be written `var allSelect = document.querySelectorAll("#govLinks select");`